# Design for multi language support in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am implementing a new sharepoint application, but the requirement is to have support for multi language on sharepoint forms.
The data stored in list columns should be multi language in different lists but in same site collection.
I want to know if we can have this possible and any thoughts on the approach i need to look at to start with.

Appreciate your inputs on this.

Thanks & Regards,
Usha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a communication site in SharePoint Online, you can take advantage of the **multilingual feature** via Site Settings > Language settings > **Enable pages and news to be translated into multiple languages**.

This setting would apply to user interface elements like site navigation, site title, and site description, and additionally, pages and news posts.

Tutorial can be found here: [Create multilingual communication sites, pages, and news.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-communication-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c)

[image]

You can also configure **variations feature** used in the process of setting up and managing multilingual sites. It would be much complicated than just using multilingual features though.

Reference: [Using the variations feature for multilingual sites.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-variations-feature-for-multilingual-sites-da0b5614-8cf5-4905-a44c-90c2b3f8fbb6)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think for the above solution we need to install language packs right?

Comment: without a language pack, i dont think we can achieve. but please correct me if there is a way without language pack.

Comment: @UshaRamani There is no need to install language packs for SharePoint in Microsoft 365. The translation will be a manual process after you enable this feature in a communication site, so you will need translators for translation. See the section “Create pages for the languages you want”: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-communication-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c#bkmk_create